# Get the header id to the details table when inserted

Tags: php

header_table
id =1

detail_table
header =1

How can I get the id of header_table if I save multiple data in detail_table.
Like for example I have 2 inserted rows and have header_id column which the header_table id can be stored. I use native PHP.

Comment: Show what have you tried..

Comment: Elaborate your question little more..

Comment: We want to see your code that have you done